# Unable to use the native Camera API with the latest Ionic

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, camera

When I run

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add @ionic-enterprise/camera
```

I get the following

```
[OK] Integration cordova added!
✔ Creating ./www directory for you - done!
> cordova plugin add @ionic-enterprise/camera

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 '@ionic-enterprise/camera' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@ionic-enterprise/camera@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/p0tta/.npm/_logs/2019-10-06T16_04_01_849Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

cordova plugin add @ionic-enterprise/camera exited with exit code 1.

Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I am using the following versions

```
$ ionic -v
5.4.2

$ node -v
v10.15.3
```

Do I need to get a more latest version of node? I have created several other non native apps with the same setup, not sure what the issue with this is.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera


$ npm install @ionic-native/camera
```

Here is help link :
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera